# DLookUp - Not pulling string from textbox on same form

Tags: filtered-lookup

Here is my string:  `DLookUp("[ExamSiteEmail]","[tblExamSite]","[ExamSite]='" & "txtExamSite" & "'")`

**Problem**: It is not pulling the string info from the combobox txtExamSite.

The problem I believe lies with how I am referencing the `combobox` `txtExamSite`. If I replace `txtExamSite` with a phrase/string that matches within the table it responds correctly with information listed in field `ExamSiteEmail`, as it should. This `Dlookup` string is being used for the default value of a `textbox` on the same form as the combobox `txtExamSite`.

How do I solve this issue?

Update: I changed the string to: =DLookUp("[ExamSiteEmail]","[tblExamSite]","[ExamSiteID]= " & [txtExamSite]).  Even though the combobox shows a string, the dlookup was pulling a value. Is this the proper syntax?  It seems to work but doesn't mean it right. Thank you.